# List View displaying Pictures

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am using a ListView control to display Pictures along with description and caption.  I used to save the full path of the image in the url field, so when I display them in the ListView I don't need to edit anything.  Now I am using something like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/photos/") + savedURL
```

How can I edit my ListView to make it show the images?

I used to do the same to GridView when in GridViews RowDataBound event I manipulate the contents like:

```
Dim photo As New Image
        photo.ImageUrl = "~/photos/" + e.Row.Cells(TheCellNumber).Text
        e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Clear()
        e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(photo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use Image control in ItemTemplate :

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="pictureId">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image
        id="pictureControlID" runat="server" AlternateText='<% #Eval("pictureName") %>'
        ImageUrl='<%# "~/photos/" + Eval("picturePath") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
ResolveUrl("~/photos/") + savedURL;
```

Comment: Try it where? I did not edit the list view, I am asking how to edit it to make it work with HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/photos/") + savedURL or the code you suggested, where should I edit?

Comment: Can you post the code for your listview (or whatever your currently doing) so we can see where you're going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a Repeater and just setting the repeater's template to display exactly like you need?  Was there any specific reason you wanted to use a ListView over a Repeater?